# How to dynamically load a Vue component after using require.context?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-mix

Currently I am loading all of my Vue components with `require.context`, this searches my `components` directory with a regex for `.vue` files. This works fine but I would like to load async components as well with dynamic imports.

Currently when I use `require.context` all files get loaded so even If I want to use a dynamic import my file is already loaded and nothing happens.

I need a way to exclude certain files from my `require.context` call. I cannot dynamically create a regex because this does not work with `require.context`.

```
// How I currently load my Vue components.

const components = require.context('@/components', true, /[A-Z]\w+\.vue$/);

components.keys().forEach((filePath) => {
    const component = components(filePath);
    const componentName = path.basename(filePath, '.vue');

    // Dynamically register the component.
    Vue.component(componentName, component);
});

// My component that I would like to load dynamically.
Vue.component('search-dropdown', () => import('./search/SearchDropdown'));
```

It seems the only way to do this is either manually declare all my components, which is a big hassle.

Or to create a static regex that skips files that have `Async` in their name. Which forces me to adopt a certain naming convention for components that are async. Also not ideal.

Would there be a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

```
const requireContext = require.context('./components', false, /.*\.vue$/)

const dynamicComponents = requireContext.keys()
    .map(file =>
        [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.vue$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
    )
    .reduce((components, [name, component]) => {
        components[name] = component.default || component
        return components
    }, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Works with Vue 2.7 and Vue 3.

The `lazy` mode forces `requireContext` to [return a promise](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext).

```js
const { defineAsyncComponent } = require('vue')

const requireContext = require.context('./yourfolder', true, /^your-regex$/, 'lazy')
module.exports = requireContext.keys().reduce((dynamicComponents, file) => {
  const [, name] = file.match(/^regex-to-match-component-name$/)
  const promise = requireContext(file)
  dynamicComponents[name] = defineAsyncComponent(() => promise)
  return dynamicComponents
}, {})
```

You can also use `defineAsyncComponent({ loader: () => promise })` if you want to use the extra options of [`defineAsyncComponent`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#loading-and-error-states).